# Select the first field from jQuery autocomplete function automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I mouseover a field in my autocomplete list it adds a class named selected. I want it to do that by default on the first line as soon as you start typing. How would i select the first element in that list and change it's class?

I'm using this now but it flickers a lot.

```
$('.name').eq(0).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm betting the flicker is caused by calling it on every keyup event. You need to 'debounce' the function call.

### Debouncing functions with jQuery:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Like this:

```
$('input:text').keyup( $.debounce( 250, function() {
  // run autocomplete routine / ajax call here
  $('.name').eq(0).addClass('selected');
}) );
```

That requires a jQuery plugin of course, so if you'd rather have a minimal-footprint version, use [John Hann](http://unscriptable.com)'s [pure-Javascript version](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/):

### Debouncing functions with pure Javascript and less code:

Or if you don't want to use another plugin, debouncing is as easy as:

```
var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {

  var timeout;

  return function debounced () {
    var obj = this, args = arguments;
    function delayed () {
        if (!execAsap)
            func.apply(obj, args);
        timeout = null; 
    };

    if (timeout)
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    else if (execAsap)
        func.apply(obj, args);

    timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100); 
  };
};
```

Usage:

```
$('input:text').keyup( debounce(function() {
  // run autocomplete routine / ajax call here
  $('.name').eq(0).addClass('selected');
}), 250, false );
```

Comment: I will try that, would prefer not to use more plugins tho.

Comment: @Sebastian: Makes sense - I added the plain-Javascript `debounce()` function too

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use jQuery's `toggleClass()` and `first()` for that.

```
$('.name').first().toggleClass('selected');
```

Comment: It still flickers, in which event should i place this code? Right now it's in a keyup event..

Comment: `toggleClass` will actually make the flickering worse - it will deselect the first element every other time it's called